# AppCode - UI Designer plugin

Tags: xcode, plugins, appcode

I trying to install [UI Designer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7807?pr=) to AppCode 2016.1.1 (Xcode 7.3) and I always get this error msg: Plugin `AppCode UI Designer` is incompatible with this installation. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/idTdf.png). JetBrains say on [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/2016.1/ui-designer.html?origin=old_help) that "UI Designer currently doesn't support Xcode 6", does it also mean no support for Xcode 7?

Thanks

Comment: Just tried to download latest app code - Looks like it its still not working.  Quickest evaluation ever.  With Xcode going downhill - JB have a chance to sign up new customers if they can get it working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry for this issue, situation is the following:

1. UI designer plugin is currently not in active development and it's not compatible with the AppCode 2016.1.
2. Recently we discovered that some of the help resources regarding UI designer were outdated and confused our users, for now all these resources are up-to-date.
3. The plugin itself is preserved for compatibility reasons and it cannot be used with the AppCode 2016.1

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are you planning to start development on designer sometime soon? I love AppCode and JetBrains but due to lack of designer in AppCode I still have to use Xcode (which I hate because of it`s bugs).

Comment: Currently the main focus are language support tasks (Swift, mixed code, Objective-C), so I think we will not start it in the near future.

Comment: you should then. we're forced to use two IDE right now, small language bits could wait. appcode now is like a car that needs another one to turn on the engine because the clutch isn't pretty enough yet according to it's engineers.

Comment: @CptEric We understand, but the amount of work to bring refactoring and other smart code editing features to the Swift/mixed code world is not "small language bits". It's a huge amount of work on language-related features and we have a clear understanding of how to implement them. In case of UI designer we have no interface format specification, no API, frequent changes in interface formats etc. As a product team we need to choose, our long-term decision is to focus on smart code-editing features. If we will have a time in the future - we will decide if we will try to make UI designer.

Comment: i'm sorry if it sounded too harsh, but it's really frustating needing to have two IDE's open heavily (atleast one, i'm looking at you, xcode) consuming the already shrinking resources(for no reason at all, damn you apple) of my mac.

Comment: I have to honestly say as much as I like the extra functionality of AppCode, without a decent alternative to Interface Builer it's not worth the price. I don't want to use 2 IDEs to build one project.

Comment: Are you guys hiring?  Maybe some of these folks clamoring for UI Designer want to put in some hours on it? :P

Comment: Also, +1 on getting UI Designer development going... I'm forced to switch back to Xcode, which is really terrible.

Comment: @gred Even if we'll hire somebody, we won't spent his time on making a copy of UI designer for now. For now we need to bring the same editing features as in Objective-C to Swift. It means that the most of refactorings should be presented, cause here we can give much better experience. Yes, you cannot edit interfaces in AppCode. In AppCode you can automatically change the function signature across the whole project, you can Rename Swift entities, you have the Introduce Variable and in fact you can refactor your code on the daily basis in Objective-C. We need to bring it to Swift first.

Comment: @gred Sorry for being too harsh, it wasn't intentional. In fact, here I just prefer to give an honest answer to make the situation clear - and that's sad that I cannot give an answer "yes, we will do it". I hope that in the future I will :)

Comment: :D no offense taken, I'll just hold off on using AppCode until I hear that it has an IB equivalent!  Best of luck!

Comment: @gred you are making a mistake - it's a great tool with a lot of features you won't find in Xcode and it will easily save you hours of development time refactoring - it will quickly pay for itself - not to mention that nowadays you get a lot of tools (for Java, Python, etc) for a very accessible yearly price. I am a huge fan of their tools and they could charge more and I would gladly pay more.

Comment: @ank I'm a huge fan as well.  In fact, I've got a subscription to all of their tools including AppCode.  You're preaching to the choir ;)  If I need to use the refactoring at some point I will of course.

Comment: Now that Apple decided to throw out the Xcode-plugin community, AppCode could become a serious competitor to Xcode. Even though I like AppCode, I preferred to stay in Xcode because I much more often switch between code editing and UI editor than I do heavy refactoring where AppCode helps a lot. The removal of plugins means a big loss of productivity. I also wanted to start writing a plugin extending IB to support my binding framework. Xcode w/o plugins and AppCode w/o UI editor is a really frustrating experience. Nowhere to go...

Answer (score 2):

Plugin does not work on a stable version, because it's hard to follow Apples changes in formats and features for storyboard files. Actually the plugin doesn't support Swift and MacOS.

Watch for changes [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7807?pr=)